# ng-class with a complex expression

Tags: angularjs

I have this code:

```
<button class="btn"
   ng-class="{btn-success: (qus.q.questionNumber == (qus.qs.length - 1))}"
   ng-disabled="qus.q.questionNumber == (qus.qs.length - 1)">
```

When I look in the Chrome developer tools I see that disabled=disabled but the class of btn-success is not set.

Is ng-class not able to deal with an expression like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly quote `btn-success` token in the expression, otherwise (because of `-`) entire expression is invalid:

```
ng-class="{'btn-success': (qus.q.questionNumber == (qus.qs.length - 1))}"
```

Note, that like in normal javascript, object key in Angular expression must be a valid identifier (alphanumeric, _ or $) and otherwise be wrapped in quotes (string key can contain anything).